# Android Uploading a file on ftp

Tags: android, file-upload

### Android file uploading issue

I am trying to upload image on my ftp server ,its not giving me any exception or error but image in nt deployed.Can anyone working on uploading image can identify problem.

```
FTPClient con = new FTPClient();

    try{
    con.connect("host",21);

    con.login(username, pswd);

    con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    con.setFileTransferMode(FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE);
    con.setSoTimeout(10000);
    con.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    if (con.login(username, pswd)) {
        try {
            File sFile = new File("mnt/sdcard/DCIM/download.jpg");
            // connect.setText(sFile.toString());
            BufferedInputStream buffIn = null;
            buffIn = new BufferedInputStream(
                    new FileInputStream(sFile));
            try {
                String fileName = sFile.getName();
                while (!dataUpResp) {
                    dataUpResp = con.storeFile(fileName,
                            buffIn);

                    // publishProgress("" + 10);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }

    }
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Comment: Dude... code, logs, etc?

Comment: Give us more info! Like a bit of your code!

Comment: Are you sure your file path is correct? you're missing the leading "/" so I suspect you're not.

Comment: when i placed some TextView to check it i found out it not crossing " if (con.login(username, pswd)) "..

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it an issue that there are 2 times logging in in your code?

```
con.login(username, pswd); // 1st time

con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
con.setFileTransferMode(FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE);
con.setSoTimeout(10000);
con.enterLocalPassiveMode();
if (con.login(username, pswd)) // 2nd time
```

Also you didn't use logout/disconnect for FTPClient and there are no flush and close for streams.
Tried your code with commons-net-3.2.jar with conjunctions of FileZilla FTP Server and it works fine.